# Discontinuous Functions on the Real Line

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

I want to prove that given any function $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that its restriction to the integers is equal to g and such that it not continuous in any restriction of the domain to any open set in $\mathbb{R}$.  I want to prove that such a function exists in ZF Set theory.  My math teacher said I would probably need the axiom of choice.  Could someone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:  do you know any functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$that are discontinuous everywhere?  Can you adapt one to this purpose?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that any exist in ZF set theory.  Do you know how?

Comment: I think the problem is essentially showing a everywhere discontinuous function exists. It should be obvious how to modify to do what you want.

Comment: I don't see where choice comes in for the classic $h(x)=0$ on the rationals, $1$ on the irrationals, but I'm not an expert.